# Ecto many_to_many associations don't edit changeset

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've been trying to get a join table working using Ecto's many_to_many field mapping -- and it could just be I don't understand how preloading should work, but whenever I try to update my associations (and by doing so, insert into my join table), I end up with an empty changeset and a new DB field that has nil for both foreign keys. I'm pretty new to Phoenix and Ecto, and my googling hasn't gotten me very far since many_to_many is relatively new in Ecto and there isn't a lot of documentation.

My Models:

```
defmodule SslStorage.Cert do
  use SslStorage.Web, :model
  alias SslStorage.User
  alias SslStorage.UsersCerts

  schema "certs" do
    field :domain, :string
    field :port, :integer
    field :issuer, :string
    field :expiration, :string
    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: UsersCerts
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:domain, :port, :issuer, :expiration])
    |> validate_required([:domain, :port, :issuer, :expiration])
  end
end

defmodule SslStorage.User do
  use SslStorage.Web, :model
  alias SslStorage.Cert
  alias SslStorage.UsersCerts

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    many_to_many :certs, Cert, join_through: UsersCerts
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:email])
    |> validate_required([:email])
  end
end

defmodule SslStorage.UsersCerts do
  use SslStorage.Web, :model
  alias SslStorage.User
  alias SslStorage.Cert

  schema "users_certs" do
    belongs_to :users, User
    belongs_to :certs, Cert
    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    # my first clue something was funky:
    # casting and validating user_id & cert_id kept breaking things
    |> cast(params, [])
    # |> validate_required([:user_id, :cert_id])
  end
end
```

The offending controller code (mostly copied from [Elixir ecto 2 create many_to_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529720/elixir-ecto-2-create-many-to-many-association))

```
new_cert = Storage.get_or_create_cert(params)
current_user = Storage.get_or_create_user(params)

change = new_cert
  |> Repo.preload(:users)
  |> Cert.changeset(%{users: [current_user]})
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:users, [current_user])
IEx.pry
change |> Repo.update!()
```

If I check the change variable from my breakpoint:

```
pry(6)> change
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{users: [#Ecto.Changeset<action: :update, changes: %{},
     errors: [], data: #SslStorage.User<>, valid?: true>]}, errors: [],
 data: #SslStorage.Cert<>, valid?: true>
pry(7)> change.data
%SslStorage.Cert{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "certs">,
 domain: "spiceworks.com", expiration: "time", id: 1,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-31 15:00:49>, issuer: "me.com",
 port: 2222, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-08-31 15:00:49>, users: []}
```

Somehow the association isn't being created as I would expect, and could use guidance.
Naturally, when the Repo.update is called, I get a new field in my database with both user_id: nil and cert_id: nil.

My main questions are:

1. Can I even accomplish a join table with Ecto associations as I'm attempting it, and if so...
2. What am I doing wrong, because I'm a little lost in Ecto land.