# How to insert IDs into a `many_to_many` association

Tags: elixir, ecto

In Ecto, is there a way to set a `many_to_many` association with just IDs (for efficiency)?  In `ActiveRecord` I would be able to say:

```
object.association_ids = [1,2]
```

In Ecto I seem to need to not only `preload` the association, but also set the new values for the association with full objects.  I can see needing to load IDs so that you could compare them in memory and only add / remove the rows that are / aren't needed.  I'd also be fine with just one query that says "remove the IDs which aren't in this list" and one set of queries to insert IDs (or to insert all IDs with one query.  My SQL is a bit rusty and so I don't remember if that's possible)

Comment: Could you outline how your schemas look?
If you have a schema for the association, then you can just insert an entry (of the schema) with both id's into the database. See also the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529720/elixir-ecto-2-create-many-to-many-association#35684320

Comment: I didn't get what you were saying at first, but I get it coming back to it now.  I don't have a schema for the join table, but it would be easy enough so I'll do that.  It's probably just a feature that I was expecting from `ActiveRecord`, but in the context of a repository pattern it probably doesn't make as much sense to have associations which represent a join table.  Thanks ;)